# BlockUI when using a popup from serverside

Tags: jquery, asp.net, colorbox

I am using an UpdatePanel to block the UI on a long process, my problem that is it works when I put a simple button, but when the button is within a popup it doesn't work(simply gets stuck untill the process is done without blocking the ui).

Code that works:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lb_start" />
  </Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="upprogress" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updatePanel" DisplayAfter="0">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/iguloader-yashar.gif" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..." Style="padding: 10px; position: fixed; top: 45%; left: 50%;" />
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lb_start" class="btn btn-success" OnClick="lb_start_Click"><i class="fa fa-start"></i> Start</asp:LinkButton>            
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Server side:

```
protected void lb_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //long process
}
```

Code that doesn't work(Uses colorbox.js):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lb_start" />
  </Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="upprogress" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updatePanel" DisplayAfter="0">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/iguloader-yashar.gif" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..." Style="padding: 10px; position: fixed; top: 45%; left: 50%;" />
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <a runat="server" id="a_start" class="inline" href="#startModal" title="Start scan"><span  class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span></a>        
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<div id="startModal" style="padding:10px; background:#fff;">
    <h2>Start Scan</h2>
    Click ok to continue:
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lb_start" class="btn btn-success" OnClick="lb_start_Click"><i class="fa fa-start"></i> Start</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Tried playing with it a little, Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what button you want to click and what the desired outcome/issue is.

Comment: You have a button and then an update panel with a link on it.  What's the story?  Do you click the link, and this then overlays the panel with the button?  What is it you want to happen when you click the button - do you want the panel overlay to disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this task using a jQuery plugin known as blockui (funny enough).

This link here shows an example: https://gist.github.com/whoshotjr/3010693

Simply include the jquery.blockui.js available from http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Then include this code in your project:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Page = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        Page.add_beginRequest(OnBeginRequest);
        Page.add_endRequest(endRequest);

        function OnBeginRequest(sender, args) {
            $.blockUI();
        }
        function endRequest(sender, args) {
            $.unblockUI();
        }

 </script>
```

Since you are running client side you'd almost always have to use Javascript to block UI while performing a web request. I've used a similar setup to this in MVC but it is all the same in the end. Hope this helps!

Comment: well done, finally such simple answer, you would think i would have gotten this answer on the first time i asked this simple question

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I would've answered sooner but I've just gotten back onto SO after some downtime.